# js: Multiple return in Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, return, ternary-operator

For my task, I have a done a piece of code like to fetch the user details,

```
var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    if (element[9].search("Active") != -1) {
        return {
            'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
            'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
            'UserName': element[3],
            'IsActiveUser': "True"
        };
    }
    else {
        return {
            'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
            'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
            'UserName': element[3],
            'IsActiveUser': "False"
        };
    }
}
```

which is working properly and i can see all the details of all the user in variable data.

While re factoring, I was asked to implement this using Ternary Operator(No guess why I have to change like this,though that one works fine). So I tried like this, code executed but only NULL value I can see in variable data.

```
var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    (element[9].search("Active")) != -1  ? {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'IsActiveUser': "True"
    } : {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'IsActiveUser': "False"
    };
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you are missing the `return` keyword

Comment: Where's the `return` keyword?

Comment: Yeah I have missed out that `return`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the difference is only one property (`IsActiveUser`), you can insert the comparison inside the object.

```
var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    return {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'IsActiveUser': ~element[9].search("Active") ? "True": "False" // really a string?
    };
});
```

Comment: Since number of lines matters, i go with this.

Comment: @Agnes Gru Steven, thanks for the attempt to edit. you wer part rigt, there was a bracket wrong and one missing.

Comment: Thanks, This may helps others too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `map` function needs to return something on each iteration. Just add the `return` keyword:

```
var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    return (element[9].search("Active")) != -1  ? {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'IsActiveUser': "True"
    } : {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'IsActiveUser': "False"
    };
}
```