# Java Script: Nested Return Statement, return inside Return

Tags: javascript, if-statement, knockout.js, return

In one of my previous question [js: Multiple return in Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148888/js-multiple-return-in-ternary-operator) I asked about returning multiple parameter with ternary-operator. But now the parameter **IsActveUser boolean(true|false)** flag have been modified to **integer(0|1|2|3) flag**,

Previously it has only two states,

```
True - Valid User
False - InValid User
```

now it has four states,

```
0 - InValid User
1 - Valid User
2 - Future User
3 - Expired User
```

So previously, I have coded like,

```
var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    return {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'IsActiveUser': ~element[9].search("Valid") ? "True": "False" // really a string?
    };
)}
```

Now I have to check like this, for four status flag

```
var data = userInfo.map(function (item) {
    if (item[9].search("title = \"Expired\"")) {
        return {
            'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(item[1]),
            'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(item[2]),
            'UserName': item[3],
            'UserStatusFlag': 3 // flag should be 3 in this case
        };
    }
    else if (item[9].search("title = \"Valid\"")) {
        return {
            'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(item[1]),
            'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(item[2]),
            'UserName': item[3],
            'UserStatusFlag': 1 // flag should be 1 in this case
        };
    }
    else if (item[9].search("title = \"Invalid\"")) {
        return {
            'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(item[1]),
            'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(item[2]),
            'UserName': item[3],
            'UserStatusFlag': 0 // flag should be 0 in this case
        };
    }
    else if (item[9].search("title = \"Future\"")) {
        return {
            'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(item[1]),
            'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(item[2]),
            'UserName': item[3],
            'UserStatusFlag': 2 // flag should be 2 in this case
        };
    }
});
```

but this is not working as expected in Knockout JS.

Shall I use anything like this, else-if checking inside return satement

```
var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    return {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'UserStatusFlag': if(~element[9].search("Valid")) {1}
                                    else if (~element[9].search("InValid")) {0}
                                    else if (~element[9].search("Future")) {2}
                                    else if (~element[9].search("Expired")) {3}
    };
})
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Why not make it a function call with a simple switch that returns a value?

Comment: maybe you could add some examples of `element`?

Comment: _How exactly_ is it not working as expected? What are example values of `item[9]`? Is it `item[9]` or `element[9]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript `if` is not an expression so it does not have a return value. But you can use the `ternary operator` (it's acctually called `conditional operator` in JavaScript)

I assume that the reason why your code is not working is that `String.prototype.search` returns the index of the found string or -1 if the string was not found. Depending on your data you might not need to use search and can just compare the sting directly. So instead of

```
item[9].search("title = \"Valid\"")
```

you have to use

```
item[9].search("title = \"Valid\"") > -1
```

or you can do what you did in your 2nd example and use the tilde (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12299678/6430127))

```
~item[9].search("title = \"Valid\"")
```

So you could use:

```
item[9].search('title = "Expired"') > -1 ? 3 :
item[9].search('title = "Valid"')   > -1 ? 1 :
item[9].search('title = "Invalid"') > -1 ? 0 :
item[9].search('title = "Future"')  > -1 ? 2 :
(()=> { throw Error(item[9] + ' is not a valid state' ) })()
```

Of course a switch or a map might also work.

Comment: That's Really Great! It Worked. Considering the code efficiency and code line matters I will go with this.

Comment: Is it really more efficient to do multiple `if`s versus an object lookup?

Comment: I do not exactly know how expensive an object lookup is compared to multiple `if`s. But I am not sure if there is a valid solution using an object lookup for this question. In the question `String.prototype.search` is used and depending on the data in element[9] this might be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Make a function call, use a switch statement

```
function getCode (item) {
    switch (item) {
        case "InValid User" : 
            return 0;
        case "Valid User" :
            return 1;
        case "Future User" :
            return 2;
        case "Expired User" :
            return 3;
    }
}
```

and call it when you build the object

```
var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    return {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'UserStatusFlag': getCode(element[9])
    };
});
```

or you can use an object instead of a switch

```
var states = {
  "InValid User" : 0,
  "Valid User" : 1,
  "Future User" : 2,
  "Expired User" : 3
};

var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    return {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'UserStatusFlag': states[element[9]]
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I detest `switch` and `if` blocks for this. An `object` mapping works so much better:

```
var USER_LOOKUP = {
    "InValid User" : 0,
    "Valid User" : 1,
    "Future User" : 2,
    "Expired User" : 3
};

var data = userInfo.map(function (element) {
    return {
        'LastName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[1]),
        'FirstName': Capitalizefirstletter(element[2]),
        'UserName': element[3],
        'UserStatusFlag': USER_LOOKUP[element[9]]
    };
)};
```

Comment: What are you doing with `USER_LOOKUP[~element[9]]`?  Looking at the question it looks like `element[9]` contains a string and you'd want to get a string as well to use as a key for USER_LOOKUP.

Comment: Stupid copy and paste. Fixed. Sorry!